# How do I change the CSS of child of an a-element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting a bit confused with my work.
My Problem is, I want to change a Element that's covered with an Element.

the HTML-structure:

```
<ul class="calendar-content">
 <li>
   <a href="#day02" onClick="popup('02');">
     <span class="day"><strong>02</strong></span>
     <span class="content" id="content">
       <small>02</small>
       <strong>Inhalt Tag 01</strong>
     </span>
    </a>
 </li>
```

The user is only seeing the first span(class=day). After a click on the link the 
second span(class=content) should "appear".
My first idea was:

```
  .calender-content .a:visited .content{
  display:block;
  }
```

Or this one:

```
  //.calender .content got margin-left:120px and is out of view
  .calender-content .a:visited .content{
  margin-left:0px;
  }
```

But nothing happens. Maybe it isn't valid but I saw stuff like this before.
I just want to display the second span after the link is visited.
Either setting the display style to block or changing the margin to 0 and animate that with
-transition.
But nothing the styles doesn't appear on the span element.

If there's a way arround in CSS, that would be great. So I don't have to use JS.

Cheers Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
.calendar-content a:visited .content { display: block; }
```

You have ".a", which means "elements with class 'a'", not "elements with tag name 'a'" :-)

Now the thing is, I'm not sure that ":visited" will be "true" (or whatever the appropriate term would be) if your `<a>` tag isn't really something that "visits" another URL.  If that's the case, then your event handler can add a class to the anchor.  If your event handler does allow the anchor to move to the label, then I think it should work.

Comment: I don't know why, but `:visited` works, still rules don't apply to its child elements. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jhg3/).

Comment: when i tested it, it does add the display:block to the child element, can you be more clear about what "rules" dont apply ?

Comment: `:visited` doesn't mean "something that visits another URL" but ["something that's been visited"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes), i.e. your browser has already been to the destination. This can be used for history sniffing and is therefore [blocked](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) for most properties in Firefox. This is probably the cause for @bazmegakapa's remark.

Comment: Yes; sorry, I wasn't clear.  I do know what it means.  What I was trying to express was that I'm not sure what happens if the event handler (which we can't see) prevents the default action of the "click". If that's the case, will ":visited" be active?  What about if the label ("#day02") has been scrolled to, or reached by another similar `<a>`?  If more specificity is needed, adding a class from the handler is probably the right approach.

Comment: I am not certain how `:visited` behaves for internal links. Anyway, you shouldn't rely on it, as stated in my comment. I added a different answer that offers another solution with the `:target` pseudo-class.

Comment: Oh shame on me. Just that little dot. missed the forest for the trees.
Yeah u r right :visited doesn't work at all, but I will try it with :target. Cheers for the really quick answer!!
I will post if I got a solution for my problem.
Hope to find one soon, cause that project gonna be an advent calender. Cheers Dan

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is the `.` notation that means "class" and not "tag". See @Pointy's answer for details and fix.

But then, you shouldn't rely on `:visited`. Indeed, it can be used for history sniffing, and browsers will probably end up removing support for most CSS properties that change layout (such as `display`), just like [Firefox already does](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/).

A pure CSS solution would be to use the [`:target` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo). However, it is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=target) in IE ≤ 8. If it is a requirement, you should go to JS.

Any way you choose, you should refactor your markup. The link should not contain something it toggles. `<small>` is a good example of an awful markup-as-presentation use. Use a `class`ed span.